# Menu bar items tightly packed on some programs but not all

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, plasma

The menu items in the [CUA-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) menu bar are packed next to each other with seemingly no space, making it harder to read. I'm not sure why, but Firefox and Konsole does not have this problem, but Evolution and some others do have it.

Is there a way to increase the space between File, Edit, Tools, Syntax, Buffers, Window, Help?

[image]

```
>echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
plasma
>cat /etc/*release
edora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="28 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=28
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f28"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 28 (Workstation Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:28"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=28
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=28
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy"
VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
VARIANT_ID=workstation
Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)

>plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.13.5
>kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.11.3
KDE Frameworks: 5.55.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Comment: Evolution is GTK related application so problem can be in your GTK settings. I feel that Plasma even has a GTK configurator in system settings by default. Check it.